# RabbitMQ : how to create and restore backup

Tags: backup, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and i need some help.
how to do backup and restore to RabbitMQ, and what is the important data i need to save.

thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you have the management plugin installed you can back-up and restore the broker on the **Overview** page.  At the bottom you will see **Import/Export Definitions** and you can use this to download a JSON representation of your broker.

This will restore Exchanges, Queues, Virtual Hosts, Policies and Users.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sounds good but is it possible to do this automatically? to schedule an import?

Comment: @lior the management plug-is has the HTTP API, so you can create an  script in python or java or what you prefer to schedule and export the configurations

Comment: but this dont back-up data from queue

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for the HTTP API endpoint, it is:

```
http://rabbit:15672/api/definitions
```

Another way to automate this is to use the command line tool `rabbitmqadmin` (http://rabbit:15672/cli/) add pass the `export` subcommand, e.g.

```
rabbitmqadmin export rabbit-backup.config
```

Comment: this just exports the configurations, not the data.

Comment: To backup data, you need to have more than one host and set a policy to "mirror the queues and exchanges", using `ha-mode: nodes
ha-sync-mode: automatic
ha-params: rabbit@rabbitmq-01
rabbit@rabbitmq-02` and apply then to all queues and exchanges. Now you have a online backup, to move that to offline backup, probably the best way is to stop that extra node rabbitmq, backup the disk and start it again. It will recover the offline time from the other node after the startup