# RabbitMQ: Message queue backup

Tags: backup, rabbitmq, restore, broker

To achieve message queue backup and restore is it enough to save the files under the Mnesia  database directory and the broker configuration? 
also do i have to stop the broker before copying the files?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ : how to create and restore backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635165/rabbitmq-how-to-create-and-restore-backup)